# spring 3 with tiles 2.2.2 and velocity integration

Tags: spring, velocity, tiles

I need to configure Tiles and Velocity with springMVC 3.0, I think I need a complete example 
on how to configure them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently went through this and described all my findings on my blog. See [Integrating Spring, Velocity and Tiles](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/02/20/spring-velocity-tile/)